# does selenium click() method work even if element is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

Selenium is not giving an error when clicking a disabled button. I am trying to click on a `BUTTON` element that gets disabled after first click.

Scenario: I'm trying to click as well as fetch text of element which got disabled and changes its text after 1st click.

```
WebElement Button = driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"));
String ValueB4click = Button.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("value = " + ValueB4click);
Button.click();
System.out.println("Button got disabled");
System.out.println("Hitting button 2nd time");
Button.click(); //----> this line should give error as button got disabled for 30 seconds after 1st click.
System.out.println("value of button after click");

String Valueafterclick = Button.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("value = " + Valueafterclick);
```

Steps are as follows:

1. value = Create PDF
2. Button got disabled
3. Hitting button 2nd time
4. value of button after click
5. value = Creating PDF...

Instead of printing until only 3rd line and then after exception summary.

Comment: i am disabling webelement using <webelement>.disabled=true or false in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

No is the short answer. Selenium is acting as a virtual keyboard & mouse essentially. You can only do with it what you normally would at a console, so a simple mouse click on a disabled element will do nothing. You would have to somehow go into the HTML/JavaScript of the page itself and re-enable the button for anything to happen with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium won't click a disabled `BUTTON`. I guess I would have thought that it would have thrown an exception like you did but I'm not able to test that right now. What you could do instead is to check the `BUTTON` to see if it's disabled after the first click.

```
WebElement Button = driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"));
System.out.println("Value of button before click: " + Button.getAttribute("value"));
Button.click();
System.out.println("Button is disabled: " + Button.isDisabled());
System.out.println("Value of button after click: " + Button.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: Thanks JeffC but i am more interested in catching exception that selenium should have thrown ....button got disabled but click() method didnt give any exception

Comment: @Vivek actually you're trying to verify disability on cached element which was already enabled, you need to refresh same element then you'll see it would throw the exception. So you should try as `driver.findElement(By.id("xyz")).click();driver.findElement(By.id("xyz")).click();`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Elements aren't cached. They are just a reference to the element. Test it for yourself.

Comment: @Vivek I just tested clicking a disabled button and it just does nothing... no exception so this is intended behavior. If the intent of the test is to make sure the button is disabled, I've given you code to accomplish that... whether or not an exception is thrown isn't really important.